# How to disable content_script.js in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I haven't installed any plugin so far in my Firefox and neither used any extra JS script till yet but I don't from where this `content_script.js` has been enabled and printing unnecessary messages in console like this :

```
 content script runtime.onMessage: update_shortcuts
content_script.js (line 91)
<System>

2 content script runtime.onMessage: tabupdate
content_script.js (line 91)
<System>
```

When i tried to look at the path of this script, it shows its a part of firefox any plugin :

[image]

> resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://22d1d103-e4d1-431c-bc5e-e2fe1cd8d902/javascripts/content_script.js

What is this script doing and how can I disable it?

I am using these extensions in FireFox:

[image]

Comment: Probably an extension of some kind. Have you tried going to that `moz-extension` URL in Firefox, and seeing what the code is? If may offer some hints.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The console messages are being caused by the Awesome Screenshot addon. Disable it and they'll stop.

If you're on Windows I recommend [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) as a very good open-source alternative to Awesome Screenshot.

Comment: Yeah.. messages gone after disabling awesome screenshot.. thanks alot..!!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's an issue of any firefox addons that you are using. Try using firefox without loading any addons and see if this issue persists.

DO this to load without addons

```
Launch Mozilla Firefox, click the "Firefox" button, click the small arrowhead next to "Help" and click "Restart with Add-Ons Disabled" in the submenu. Click the "Restart" button to confirm the action and restart Mozilla Firefox. Click the "Start in Safe Mode" button to start Mozilla Firefox without the add-ons.
```

Comment: Can you please mention how we can load firefox without plugins..??

Comment: I have updated my question with list of plugins am using with FireFox..!!

Comment: @Ritesh : I have updated my answer. Please follow along.

Comment: I have started FireFox disabling all the add-ons but now i can't even open firebug.. lolzz..!!

Comment: @Ritesh : In-case, you forgot, firebug is also an addons to mozilla. Use the built in developer tools.

Comment: Please go through the question once again.. i need to disable that unnecessary script only not all the plugins..!!

Comment: @Ritesh : You need to carefully consider about the way of debugging. First, see if your script works after disabling all the addons. If Yes, then go back and enable all addons.. Then disable one by one and test. You will find the main culprit in this way.

Comment: @Flowgram solved this issue.. please check the accepted answer once..!! thanks for your precious time..!!

Comment: @Ritesh : What I have answered to you was how to debug this issue. In future if this types of error appears, you know how to solve that. I am not gonna install all the addons you listed to check which was in fault. If you want to criticize someone, please look at the mirror.

Comment: I am neither criticizing any one nor telling you to install all plugins i have listed. I have mentioned the list so anyone like @Flowgram had faced this issue can be confirm its the same issue.. for your answer.. i didn't asked way for debugging.. i asked for solution which i got from other user.. so keep calm and keep codding.. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Note: These instructions are used to turn off JavaScript completely. However, the question was about turning off only one script, not everything. Though I am sharing with you.

Here are the steps:

**Step 1**
Open Firefox In the address bar, type about:config then press Enter on your keyboard Please note, if your version of Firefox was pre-installed on your machine or device, altering settings in this was may void your warranty

**Step 2**
Click on the I’ll be careful, I promise! button to continue

**Step 3**
In the search bar, type javascript.enabled to find the preference option of the same name

**Step 4**
Right-click on the javascript. enabled option, then click on the Toggle menu item The Value column should now read as false, meaning JavaScript is disabled. A Value of true means JavaScript is enabled

**Step 5**
Restart Firefox then visit whatismyipaddress.ricmedia.com to confirm JavaScript status

Comment: These instructions are great if you want to turn off JavaScript completely. However, the question was about turning off only one script, not everything.