# Prevent "content script runtime.onMessage: tabupdate" on firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, content-script

In my project I am using bootstrap modals and tables. I found that for some requests the page showing error

> content script runtime.onMessage:  tabupdate

On file

> moz-extension://cda0358a-3bec-4b1f-bb1c-3b6865f041e2/javascripts/content_script.js

I can't understand why it is showing and how to prevent it(**It showing in mozilla firefox only**). And I didn't find any suitable help also.

**Is it possible to prevent this error?**

Any help could be appreciatd.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated with [How to disable content_script.js in firefox..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864066/how-to-disable-content-script-js-in-firefox) .

The console messages are being caused by the Awesome Screenshot addon. Disable it and they'll stop.